# See results for multiple select queries within a transaction in toad for SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, toad

I am using TOAD for SQL Server 6.8.2.9 (64 Bit) Freeware. Is it possible to see the results of all select statements in the result sets of a transaction?   For example when I run

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;  
    SELECT * 
    FROM FORM.QuestionStore 
    WHERE QuestionId = 890; 

    UPDATE FORM.QuestionStore 
    SET QuestionSubText = 'test' 
    WHERE QuestionId = 890;

    SELECT * 
    FROM FORM.QuestionStore 
    WHERE QuestionId = 890;
ROLLBACK;
```

In my result sets tab I see the results of the second select statement (the one after the update)  but I do not see the results of the first (the one before the update). Is there an option or setting to see both of them?

Comment: do you try that query in the Management Studio?

Comment: @polzka I believe in Management Studio it behaves as I would like (it shows both) I prefer toad so I was wondering if I could set toad up to behave the same way

Comment: `2. Select Editor | Execute SQL Script in External App menu option.   This option will open Toad Quest Script Runner application.  It will open QSR in a separate window and will run all queries and place all results in the single bottom pane.` From [Can Toad be set to view multiple query results in one window at the same time?](https://support.quest.com/toad-data-point/kb/54007/can-toad-be-set-to-view-multiple-query-results-in-one-window-at-the-same-time-)

Comment: @Lukasz Szozda unfortunately not seeing that option. perhaps the freeware version does  not have it?